# Why Exponential Weighted Average in RMSProp

Tags: machine-learning, adam

In optimization algorithms such as RMSProp, Adam, etc. why is an exponential weighted average used over a straight sum and divide? Seemingly an exponential weighted average would be useful when the further away something occurred the less useful it will be in predicting what is about to happen, but that does not seem to be the case in this instance.

Comment: Why don't you think it's the case, @terribleprogrammer?

Comment: EWMA can act like a running statistic, but each new update tends to have a lower cost.  You can think of it as an alternative formulation of mean or variance.  If you like I can show you the derivation.